# How can i allow text selection in a div that contains @click event in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

when i try to select a text in a div that contains @click event, the selection can't be maintained, it disapears after clicking on the text
how can i enable text selection in that case, so that i can copy the text ?

```html
<div @click="addBuliding()" class="buildings">
  <a>Hellooo</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What do your `addBuliding` method do here ? Does it not conflict with the selection ? Also, I do recommend using `addBuliding` rather than `addBuliding()`, otherwise it will be applied when rendering rather when called by a click.

Comment: Is the `addBuilding`function supposed to retrieve the selected text?